# Why do I need 2 Console.ReadLine(); to pause the console?

Tags: c#, console.readline

I'm just learning c#, and I like to understand everything before I move on.

The problem I'm having is I need 2 Console.ReadLine(); to pause the console. If I just use 1, the program ends after the input. So why does it need 2 readline methods instead of? Any ideas?

Please note in my code, I've commented out 1 of the readline methods, the way I want my program to work but it doesn't. However removing the comments allows the program to work, but I don't understand why.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CoinFlip
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Random rng = new Random();
            Console.WriteLine(@"

This program will allow you to guess heads or tails on a coin flip.

Please enter h for heads, or t for tails and press Enter: ");

            char userGuess = (char)Console.Read();
            int coin = rng.Next(0,2);

            Console.WriteLine("Coin is {0}\n\n", coin);


            if (coin == 0 && (userGuess == 'h' || userGuess == 'H'))
            {

                Console.WriteLine("It's heads! You win!");

            }
            else if (coin == 1 && (userGuess == 't' || userGuess == 'T'))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("It's tails! You win!");

            }
            else if (userGuess != 't' && userGuess != 'T' && userGuess != 'h' && userGuess != 'H') 
            { 
                Console.WriteLine("You didn't enter a valid letter"); 
            }

            else
            {

                if (coin == 0) { Console.WriteLine("You lose mofo. The coin was heads!"); }
                if (coin == 1) { Console.WriteLine("You lose mofo. The coin was tails!"); }

            }
            Console.ReadLine();
            //Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Also note the line: Console.WriteLine("Coin is {0}\n\n", coin);

Is for so I can see the variable number myself. This will be taken out of the final program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using `Console.Read()`, which reads a single character *after the user has hit return*. However, it only consumes that single character - which means the rest of the line (even if it's empty) is still waiting to be consumed... which `Console.ReadLine()` is doing.

The simplest fix to this is to use `Console.ReadLine()` earlier too:

```
string userGuess = Console.ReadLine();
```

.. then maybe check that the guess was a single character, or just change all your character literals (e.g. `'t'`) to string literals (e.g. `"t"`).

(Or use `Console.ReadKey()` as Servy suggested. It depends on whether you want the user to hit return or not.)

Comment: Cheers guys, Wow you were super fast and explained it well.

With your explanation I added the following code at the bottom to test what you're saying:

Console.WriteLine(Console.ReadLine());
Console.ReadLine();

And then I wrote tomato

Sure enough it used the t for tails, and then read out "omato" on the console.writeline

Comment: Also I bought a book called C# In depth 3rd edition, which I plan to read after I get the basics down. Not sure if you're the same guy who wrote it or not.

Comment: @user4202953: Yes, I am. Hope you enjoy it :)

Comment: haha, in the nerdiest way possible, I just want to say I'm starstruck having my question answered by a bestselling author. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 3):

The short answer, don't use `Console.Read`.  It can't read anything until you submit a line of text, but it only reads the first character of that line of text, leaving the rest of that line for further console input, such as , say a call to `Console.ReadLine`.  Use `Console.ReadKey` instead of `Console.Read` to read a single character.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Though I understood Jon's explanation better. You did introduce me to a new method *Console.ReadKey, which I'll be sure to play with. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

The first **Console.ReadLine()** is consumed by the **Enter** key and hence the program ends.
Try this instead of **Console.Read()**

```
    var consoleKeyInfo = Console.ReadKey();
    var userGuess = consoleKeyInfo.KeyChar;
```